# Как оставить то же самое Activity, но поменять ориентацию?

Tags: android

Существует ли способ оставить тот же самой Activity, чтобы у него остались те же самые кнопки, лейауты с теми же самыми названиями, но чтобы в другой ориентации экрана элементы располагались совершенно по-другому?

Не предлагать:

- Создать новый лейаут и к нему новый класс, потому что получится неоправданное дублирование кода, а функционал у двух классов с ориентацией почти одинаковый
- Создать общий класс, который extends Activity, и от него наследовать классы с portrait и landscape ориентацией. Это не подходит, потому что мне, в зависимости от ориентации нужно менять всего один метод и он должен работать максимально быстро, т.е без всяких вызовов виртуальных и абстрактных методов

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очень просто ! лейаут для портретной ориентации лежит `res/layout`

А для ландшафт-а `res/layout-land`

Оба файла должны иметь одинаковые имена, например `activity_m.xml`
Названия элементов - должны совпадать, расположение какое тебе вздумается !

Answer (score 4):

Почитайте в [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html) о поддержке различных экранов и ориентаций.

А если кратко - создайте папку рядом с Вашей папкой `layout/` и назовите ее `layout-land`. Скопируйте в нее необходимый Вам `xml` файл. Расставьте элементы как Вам необходимо. Главное - `id` элементов должны совпадать. Добавили что-то новое в одном, должны добавить и в другом.